# AVFoundation AVPlayer .AVI OS X

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation, avplayer, avi

everyone.

I have a problem with playing .avi video, in AVPlayer.

When I load it with `loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys` e.g. `"tracks"`, but the array is empty.

Maybe someone knows, how to play .avi video (if it possible)?

Thanks for help.

Comment: AVI is not a format, it's a container.  What is the video format of the AVI file you are trying to play?

Comment: I trying to open Theatrical.avi video file. 
Do I convert this video ?